# Forwarding high quality graphics from matlab via ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg, matlab

I am connecting to a local server that runs MATLAB (version 2015a) via ssh with the X forwarding option (`ssh -X`).

However when I start MATLAB I get this warning:

```
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /lib64/libLLVM-3.5-mesa.so))
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
```

When I start MATLAB as root then instead of `Permission denied` in the first line, I get: 

`libGL error: failed to authenticate magic 1`

The graphics are terrible, even the text (See the screenshot below). I suppose this issue is related to forwarding the graphics to guest system via ssh. So I thought the display option in MATLAB can be set to the guest-system X-display which I did by:

`matlab -display guest-ip:0`

Even then I am getting the OpenGL error and there is no graphical output (matlab runs in shell and figure windows do not pop up).

The host has centos-7 and the guest has fedora-20 and both have `mesa-libGLU` installed. What is the right way to forward high quality graphics?

---

> **Host system**
>   [image]
>
> **Guest system (for comparison)**
>   [image]

Comment: I think hardware OpenGL only works locally, not via remote X, and as a consequence Matlab switches to software rendering of OpenGL. Try to use Matlab's "painters" renderer instead: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#prop_Renderer

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and solve it using the guide from: 
http://cplusadd.blogspot.com/2012/01/speeding-up-matlab-over-x11-forwarding.html
If you log into machine A via ssh from machine B, and then run the matlab terminal command in the home directory of A, create a file in the home directory titled `java.opts` with the contents:

```
-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false
```

Then ssh using these options:

```
ssh -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -Y -C username@server
```

For myself, this made running matlab over ssh much, much better.